# windows mobile nfc secure element

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nfc

I am new to windows mobile development.i want to developed application which can read secure element in mifare desfire card.i want to know in windows platform is support for desfire nfc t card.if not give some description what are the best standardized nfc format in windows platform.

Thanks
SSv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the NFC related question by mentioning Secure Element.

WP8 only supports NDEF formatted cards. Here's a sample 
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/WP8_NFC_Tutorial:_Voice_Messages_on_NFC_Tags